# Flex Viewer: How do I return a subset of the input data using the geoprocessing widget?

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-10.2, flex, widget, arcgis-flex-viewer

I have a set of point data (representing crashes) that has been published as a feature service and which I have pulled into a Flex (3.5) application. I want the users to be able to submit a query and create a subset of the original data - for example, to access all the crashes that occurred on a Tuesday, or which were fatal, etc.

To do this I have created a Geoprocessing widget based on a very simple model (Get expression, Select by attribute; copy features) that has been published as a GP service.

However, I haven't been able to get the GP widget to work properly. Once run, it adds the output 'Query' layer to the layer list, but there are no features within that layer (ie, nothing on the map).

Geoprocessing Widget config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration label="Select by Attribute">
    <taskurl>http://ags-dev2:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CAS_Crashes/SelbyAttr/GPServer/SelbyAttr</taskurl>
    <shareresults>true</shareresults>
    <inputparams>
        <param name="Expression"
               label="Expression"
               required="false"
               type="string"
               visible="true">
        </param>
    </inputparams>
    <outputparams>
        <param name="Output"
               label="Query"
               type="featurerecordset"
               visible="true"
               geometrytype="point">
            <simplerenderer>
                <simplemarkersymbol color="0x2D9C49" width="4"/>
            </simplerenderer>
        </param>
    </outputparams>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what I might need to change to bring the features through to the output layer?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2, ArcGIS Server 10.2, Flex 3.5.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. the geoprocessing fills a file-gdb, but the results are not shown. also a search on this layer return nothing. however, jsut this morning I suddenly saw points in this layer. after running the geoprocessing again, the layer was empty again. in arcmap the stuff works. I suspect some kind of caching to be responsible. I have set autorefresh and disableclientcaching for the mapservice, but no luck so far. any guru that can help us ?